# Where is System.Windows.Shell?

Tags: .net, namespaces

Basically, I want to work with a few methods inside `System.Windows.Shell` and I can't find it.

I am using .Net 4 with Visual Studio 2010 with the full .Net framework (not client profile) and I am unable to find this under the .Net tab in the add references dialogue box. Where can I find it?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.Windows.Shell Reference missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319235/system-windows-shell-reference-missing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go to the MSDN and open [the specific class you are looking for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.jumpitem.aspx) it will tell you what DLL to add in the .NET tab so the namespace will show up.

For example:

> ## JumpItem Class
>
> **Namespace:** System.Windows.Shell
>   **Assembly:**  PresentationFramework (in
>   PresentationFramework.dll)

So you would want to add the `PresentationFramework` reference in the .NET tab.